# Limiting a pan gesture recognizer to an ImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview, bounds

I have an `ImageView` containing a circular gradient and a `panGestureRecognizer` that I want to limit specifically to the gradient to prevent interference with the `UISliders` in the view or the white background.

How do I only recognize touches within the gradient?

As of now, I am using this equation with bad results :

```
        CGPoint lastPoint = [sender locationOfTouch: sender.numberOfTouches - 1 inView: gradientView];
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake((size.width/2), (size.height /2));
```

These variables are used to indicate the center of the gradient. This is the equation :

```
        if((lastPoint.x - center.x) + (lastPoint.y - center.y)/2 < radius)
        {
            UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue: angle / (M_PI * 2.0) saturation:saturationSlider.value brightness:hellSlider.value alpha:alphaSlider.value];
            if ([color getRed: &r green: &g blue:&b alpha: &a])
            {
                NSLog(@"Color value - R : %g G : %g : B %g", r*255, g*255, b*255);
            }
            float red = r;
            float green = g;
            float blue = b;
            rText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",rSlider.value];
            gText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",green*255];
            bText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",blue*255];


            colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(rText.text.floatValue/255) green:(gText.text.floatValue/255) blue:(bText.text.floatValue/255) alpha:alphaSlider.value];
            rSlider.value = red*255;
            gSlider.value = green*255;
            bSlider.value = blue*255;
            alphaText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",alphaSlider.value];
            brightnessText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",hellSlider.value];
            saturationText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",saturationSlider.value];

        }
```

This code above is inside my `panGestureRecognizer`'s method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `UIView` on the top of that circular view and apply gesture to that View.

```
UIView *gestureView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[gestureView.layer setCornerRadius:gestureView.frame.size.width/2];
```

**This will give you a circular `UIView`.**
Adjust the size and the position according to your need.

Comment: this does not disable the gradient below the views, this still giving me colors even when i drag outside the visible gradient's bounds.

Comment: what do you want to actually achieve here ?
Do you just want to restrict the touch area or anything else ?

Comment: I plan to restrict the area recognized by the gesture recognizer in order to just use the visible part of the gradient